# Support for short 3D texture in WebGL 2.0

Tags: javascript, firefox, webgl2

I am attempting to load a short 3D texture in WebGL 2.0 in Firefox.

While unsigned 1 byte 3D textures load without any problem, I am struggling to do the same for any other pixel type.
My js code:

```
var SIZE = 512;
var data = new Int16Array(SIZE * SIZE * SIZE);
data.fill(400);

var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_3D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

gl.texImage3D(
    gl.TEXTURE_3D,  // target
    0,              // level
    gl.R16I,        // internalformat
    SIZE,           // width
    SIZE,           // height
    SIZE,              // depth
    0,              // border
    gl.RED_INTEGER,         // format
    gl.SHORT,       // type
    data            // pixel
   );
```

I am not generating mip maps on this texture.

When trying to sample texture in the fragment shader I get 0 for each pixel.

FS code:

```
#version 300 es

precision highp float;
precision highp int;
precision highp sampler3D;

uniform sampler3D textureData;

in vec3 v_texcoord;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
   vec4 value = texture(textureData, v_texcoord);
   if( value.x == 0.0 )
      color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   else if( value.x == 1.0)
      color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   else if( value.x < 0.0 )
      color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   else
      color = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `isampler3D` to sample a integer format texture in which case `texture` returns an `ivec4`

[From the spec section 8.8](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/3.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.00.3.pdf)

> Texture lookup functions are provided that can return their result as floating point, unsigned integer or
>   signed integer, depending on the sampler type passed to the lookup function. Care must be taken to use
>   the right sampler type for texture access. The following table lists the supported combinations of sampler
>   types and texture internal formats. Blank entries are unsupported. Doing a texture lookup will return
>   undefined values for unsupported combinations.
>
> ```
>  Internal   
>  Texture           | Floating Point | Signed Integer | Unsigned Integer |
>  Format            | Sampler Types  | Sampler Types  | Sampler Types    |
> -------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+
>  Floating point    |   Supported    |                |                  |
> -------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+
>  Normalized Integer|   Supported    |                |                  |
> -------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+
>  Signed Integer    |                |   Supported    |                  |
> -------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+
>  Unsigned Integer  |                |                |   Supported      |
> -------------------+----------------+----------------+------------------+
> ```

```js
var gl = document.querySelector("#c").getContext("webgl2");
if (!gl) {
  alert("needs webgl 2.0");
}

var SIZE = 512;
var data = new Int16Array(SIZE * SIZE * SIZE);
data.fill(400);

var texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_3D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_3D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);

gl.texImage3D(
    gl.TEXTURE_3D,  // target
    0,              // level
    gl.R16I,        // internalformat
    SIZE,           // width
    SIZE,           // height
    SIZE,              // depth
    0,              // border
    gl.RED_INTEGER,         // format
    gl.SHORT,       // type
    data            // pixel
   );

// FS code:

var fs = `#version 300 es

precision highp float;
precision highp int;
precision highp isampler3D;

uniform isampler3D textureData;

in vec3 v_texcoord;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
   ivec4 value = texture(textureData, v_texcoord);
   if( value.x == 0 )
      color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   else if( value.x == 1)
      color = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   else if( value.x < 0 )
      color = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   else
      color = vec4(0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}
`;

var vs = `#version 300 es
in vec4 position;
out vec3 v_texcoord;
void main() {
  gl_Position = position;
  v_texcoord = vec3(0);
}
`

var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
var bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createXYQuadBufferInfo(gl);

gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; background: purple; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/2.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"><canvas>
```

Comment: That greatly helped. Thanks a lot.